# ES6: How do I unravel inner arrays and flatten the JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, lodash, transformation

Imagine that I have the following JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "team": "Colts",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Andrew Luck",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Quenton Nelson",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "team": "Patriots",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Tom Brady",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shaq Mason",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to transform and flatten the JSON to be the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Andrew Luck",
    "position": "quarterback",
    "team": "Colts"
  },
  {
    "name": "Quenton Nelson",
    "position": "guard",
    "team": "Colts"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tom Brady",
    "position": "quarterback",
    "team": "Patriots"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shaq Mason",
    "position": "guard",
    "team": "Patriots"
  }
]
```

How would I do this with either ES6 or lodash syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method along with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
let res = data.reduce((arr, { team, players }) => arr.concat(players.map( obj => ({...obj, team }))), []);

// or
let res = data.reduce((arr, { team, players }) => [...arr, ...players.map( obj => ({...obj, team }))], []);

// or
let res = data.reduce((arr, { team, players }) => (arr.push(...players.map( obj => ({...obj, team }))),arr), []);
```

```js
var data = [{
    "team": "Colts",
    "players": [{
        "name": "Andrew Luck",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Quenton Nelson",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "team": "Patriots",
    "players": [{
        "name": "Tom Brady",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shaq Mason",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let res = data.reduce((arr, {
  team,
  players
}) => arr.concat(players.map(obj => ({ ...obj,
  team
}))), []);


// or
let res1 = data.reduce((arr, {
  team,
  players
}) => [...arr, ...players.map(obj => ({ ...obj,
  team
}))], []);

// or
let res2 = data.reduce((arr, {
  team,
  players
}) => (arr.push(...players.map(obj => ({ ...obj,
  team
}))), arr), []);


console.log(res, res1, res2)
```

Answer (score 5):

With simple loops (ES2015):

```js
const players = [];
for (const team of teams) {
  for (const player of team.players) {
    players.push(Object.assign({team: team.team}, player));
  }
}
```

You can use object spread instead of `Object.assign` if your environment supports it.

With [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (will officially be part of ES2019, or use lodash):

```
const players = teams.flatMap(
  team => team.players.map(player => {...player, team: team.team})
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use lodah's `_.flatMap()` to iterate the array and flatten the result. Internally use `_.map()` to iterate the players and add the `team` using object spread:

```js
const arr = [{"team":"Colts","players":[{"name":"Andrew Luck","position":"quarterback"},{"name":"Quenton Nelson","position":"guard"}]},{"team":"Patriots","players":[{"name":"Tom Brady","position":"quarterback"},{"name":"Shaq Mason","position":"guard"}]}]

const result = _.flatMap(arr, ({ team, players }) => 
  _.map(players, o => ({ team, ...o }))
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can do the same with `Array.flatMap()` and `Array.map()`:

```js
const arr = [{"team":"Colts","players":[{"name":"Andrew Luck","position":"quarterback"},{"name":"Quenton Nelson","position":"guard"}]},{"team":"Patriots","players":[{"name":"Tom Brady","position":"quarterback"},{"name":"Shaq Mason","position":"guard"}]}]

const result = arr.flatMap(({ team, players }) => 
  players.map(o => ({ team, ...o }))
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "team": "Colts",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Andrew Luck",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Quenton Nelson",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "team": "Patriots",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Tom Brady",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shaq Mason",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const flatData = data.map(d => {
  const { team } = d
  const assignedPlayers = d.players.map(player => ({ team, ...player }))
  return assignedPlayers
}).flat()

console.log(flatData)
```

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 (spread operator) along with `reduce` and `concat`:

```js
const arr = [{
    "team": "Colts",
    "players": [{
        "name": "Andrew Luck",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Quenton Nelson",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "team": "Patriots",
    "players": [{
        "name": "Tom Brady",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shaq Mason",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  return acc.concat(...obj.players.map(player => {
    return Object.assign({
      team: obj.team
    }, player)
  }))
}, []));
```

Comment: To clarify for future visitors: `reduce` existed before ES6.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply using the following code! Check it!

```js
var inputArray = [{"team":"Colts","players":[{"name":"Andrew Luck","position":"quarterback"},{"name":"Quenton Nelson","position":"guard"}]},{"team":"Patriots","players":[{"name":"Tom Brady","position":"quarterback"},{"name":"Shaq Mason","position":"guard"}]}]

var result = [];
inputArray.forEach(function(elem) {
  const players = elem.players;
  players.forEach(function(child) {
    const obj = {};
    obj["name"] = child.name;
    obj["position"] = child.position;
    obj["team"] = elem.team;
    result.push(obj);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important; top:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative with a combination of `Array.reduce()` and `Array.forEach()`:

```js
let input = [
  {
    "team": "Colts",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Andrew Luck",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Quenton Nelson",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "team": "Patriots",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Tom Brady",
        "position": "quarterback"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shaq Mason",
        "position": "guard"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let output = input.reduce((acc, {team, players}) =>
{
    players.forEach(({name, position}) => acc.push({name, position, team}));
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```